# Multiple instances of the Mumble client

Tags: macos, terminal, software

I have tried command that I found and it works for second and after that second client closes.

```
open -na /Applications/Mumble.app
```

Other command that I tryied with the same resul.

```
/Applications/Mumble.app/Contents/MacOS/Mumble &
[2] 27307
[1]   Exit 126                /Applications/Mumble.app
```

What command I must use to have multiple Mumble instances open?

Comment: Are you sure that Mumble even supports running with several instances at once?

Comment: On Windows - I'm sure that it is possible. http://mumble.sourceforge.net/Tips_Tricks#Run_Multiple_instances_of_the_Mumble_Client

Comment: There it also says you need to specify `-m` when starting the first client, did you try that (`/Applications/Mumble.app/Contents/MacOS/Mumble -m`)

Comment: It worked but is not possible to connect as a two diffrent users.

Comment: Then you are probably better off asking at mumble.sourceforge.net directly

Answer (score 1):

What you and future searchers are looking for is this:

```
open -n /Applications/Mumble.app --args -m
```

This is valid as of 11/04/14 on OS X 10.10/Darwin 14.0.0 (Yosemite)